# How to enable hot reloading in AEM react server side rendering

Tags: reactjs, aem, server-side-rendering

I am using https://github.com/adobe/aem-sample-we-retail-journal/ this repo to setup aem react SSR. Can someone please help in how to enable hot-reloading in above?

Comment: Take a look at AEMSync for VS Code, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Yinkai15.aemsync

Comment: There are similar options for other IDEs